# Unable to view service provider under identity provider

Tags: connected-apps, saml, certificates, identity

i have enabled the identity provider setup and filled all the correct details on SAML with the Metadata, i have also created a connected app and enabled SAML and filled the Entity ID with the SimpleSamlPHP url and added my Salesforce Domain login under ACS URL however when i go back to identity provider i still cannot see any Service Providers, i enabled it under the profile i am currently using, ive run out ideas and what else to try?

Answer (score 1):

The Service Providers are not shown any more under the Service Providers section when looking at an Identity Provider. They are only listed in the Connected Apps section. I don't think it's a bug, they just decided to have them only at that other location.

Note that [this screenshot](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/File:Idpsp.png) coming from the [Implementing Single Sign-On Across Multiple Organizations](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_Single_Sign-On_Across_Multiple_Organizations) is outdated. Nothing is listed now in the Service Providers section. (But it all still works if you follow the tutorial.)

Answer (score 0):

Service providers are now moved under connected app..You will find under connected apps section.

Comment: Yeah i have created the connected App enabled saml etc, it still doesnt show up under the profile->service provider or identity provider->service provider?

Comment: Do you see under Create>Apps>Connected Apps ??

Comment: Yes i said above i have created the Connected App

Comment: Click on the manage button on the connected app and you will see the SAML info and everything you entered there..

Comment: Yeah i have entered all the relevant data but when i attempt to use Salesforce as the identity provider i get Error: Unable to resolve request into a Service Provider?

Comment: I am not sure on why you are seeing that error..Here is another post(http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/50721/unable-to-resolve-request-into-a-service-provider-return-by-salesforce-identit?rq=1) with the same error. May be you should be check the Identity Provider Event log..